# Display SQL table data in Bootstrap modal

Tags: sql, asp.net, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I have a button 'Create Roles' and on clicking it opens a bootstrap modal which has a table.
I have a Stored procedure 'usp_Show_Roles' which selects all the rows from the table 'Roles'.
I want to display the data via a stored procedure on the bootstrap model.
How can the SP be executed on the Modal, I can't think of any methods to do so.
Please help me move forward/

> Modal Code:

Create Role

```
     <table class="table-bordered" style="float: left" id=" from">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="display-5">Operation</th>
                        <th class="display-5">Operation Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

> Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Show_Roles]
  AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT = 0

    BEGIN TRY
            select RoleName,RoleDescription from Mast_Role
            SET @Result = 1

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

                SET @Result = -1

    END CATCH

SELECT @Result AS 'Result'
```

END

GO

Comment: You should read about making a post from client-side (maybe with **JQUERY AJAX**) to a **PHP** script that run on server-side and does the **SQL CALL** to the stored procedure and finish returning the data to the client-side. After you have the data on the client-side, you can fill the modal.

Comment: Since you're using asp.net mvc, pass the data to your controller, then on your controller call the stored procedure, and return necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

On the button click of "Create Roles", Call the click event function.
Within that function call the GET action method, which retrieves the data from your stored procedure and return that data.
Access the data in success function and receive the response and display on table by looping the data.